# Concate strings in python with single and double quotes is not giving right result

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, string-concatenation

How to concatenate strings in python which has single quotes and double quotes

```
a = "{'requests': [{ " 
c = '"image" : {"source" : ' 

a+c
```

is giving a "\" before the single quote

```
{\'requests\': [{ "image" : {"source" :
```

I need an output like this

```
{'requests': [{ "image" : {"source" :
```

Comment: Use three double quote, `x= """ {'requests': [{ " c = '"image" : {"source" : """`

Comment: Whatever you are outputting this to, it is escaping the quotes.

Comment: I suspect an XY problem. Why are you constructing that string? Are you trying to make a JSON object? If so, you should build a normal Python object and then convert it to JSON, don't try to cobble it together from string fragments.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with how the string actually looks like; try printing it:

```
print(a+c)
```

It is simply a matter of how Python *represents* the string in an interactive session (or when `repr()`d).

See also: [Built-in Functions: `repr()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#repr) in the Python docs.